# SwiftData specialized Schema.Relationship.init (name:valueType:keypath:metadata:)

Tags: testflight, swift-data, xcode15, ios17, swift-data-relationship

Users on TestFlight have started seeing this crash. Any suggestions?
No changes were made to the swift data schema between builds and the install works on my device.

[image]

UPDATE:
New device install error
"Thread 1: Fatal error: Unable to parse keypath for non-PersistentModel Type"

This error has now lead me to a post
[on apple dev forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/746311). As suggested there I'm going back to an old version of Xcode (15.2) to see if its 15.3 that's the issues

FIXED: going back to 15.2 has resolved the issue.

Comment: Don't you get any kind of error message?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson no none at all.

Comment: “… the install works on my device”, did you try a clean install?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson did a fresh device install and I now have error that I am investigating. OP updated