# SwiftData ModelContainer can not be created in iOS 17.4 Beta

Tags: ios, swift-data

I have an app in the app store which is working fine. Some users reported that they have app crashing when they are using iOS 17.4 beta. I could recreate the issue and it is happening when ModelContainer is crerated. This code..

```
do {
     let configuration = ModelConfiguration(for: MyTodo.self, isStoredInMemoryOnly: false)
                modelContainer = try ModelContainer(for: MyTodo.self, configurations: configuration)
    } catch {
                fatalError("Failed to load model container.\(error)")
    }
```

is throwing this error message:

```
Fatal error: Failed to load model container.SwiftDataError(_error: SwiftData.SwiftDataError._Error.loadIssueModelContainer)
```

My model do not have any @Attribute(.unique)

All properties have default values Relationships are marked as optional App is using CloudKit for iCloud syncronization

A brand new app with the same model does not have this issue. When I uncheck "CloutKit" in Signing & Capabilities, the app launch normally.

Widget can obtain the data without error/crash from modelContainer using this code:

```
guard let modelContainer = try? ModelContainer(for: MyTodo.self) else {
     return []
}
```

Edit: I have now identified that this issue is happening due to Relationships in my model.
My MyToDo has task defined like this:

```
@Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade) var tasks: [MyTask]? = []
```

and MyTask has reference back as following:

```
var todo: MyTodo?
```

Both of them are optional as required for CloudKit. This model can be read in iOS 17.3, but in 17.4 beta, it crashes!

Comment: Maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78007588/swiftdata-specialized-schema-relationship-init-namevaluetypekeypathmetadata) is related, if so I guess you need to wait for a fix from Apple

Comment: Thanks @JoakimDanielson, it does not seem to be related. The issue is related to the relationships. It works in Widget, it works in iOS 17.3, but model can not be read in iOS 17.4 beta!

Answer (score 0):

It seems for whatever reason inverse relationship needs to be explicitly defined. Change from this:

```
@Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade) var tasks: [MyTask]? = []
```

to

```
@Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \MyTask.todo) var tasks: [MyTask]? = []
```

has solved the crash issue. Works both in iOS 17.3 and 17.4.